Pyomo Piecewise constraint with differently indexed variables
I am facing some difficulties with a model I'm working on in Pyomo.
I want to use a Piecewise constraint for which pyomo has a built-in constraint. I have one variable, $P_{loss}$, which is indexed by $dir, n$ and $t$, as well as the variable $P$, which is indexed by $dir, n, t$ and $flow$. I want to map values from $P$ to $P_{loss}$ via the piecewise linear regression implemented in the Piecewise constraint. Here, only the values from $P$ where $flow == in$ are required.
Now, Pyomo requires the variables for x and y to be indexed equally - but I can't tell the Piecewise definition that index $flow$ of $P$ should be fixed to value $in$.
So, how can I approach this? My ideas so far:

Just index $P_{loss}$ additionally with $flow$, but don't use the values with $flow \neq in$. But this doubles the number of variables (there is just two values in the $flow$ index). And lots of unnecessary calculation.
Add an additional variable $P_{inflow}$, which is defined simply via the constraint: $P[dir, n, t, in] = P_{inflow}[dir, n, t]$. Supply $P_{inflow}$ and $P_{loss}$ (which are indexed equally) to Piecewise constraint. Still, additional variables but no further calculation. But also additional constraints for setting P_{inflow}.
Implement my own piecewise constraint, which allows me to just index only $flow = in$ inside the rule definition. But this would be additional effort, especially if I need to try several Piecewise formulations - and it's already there in Pyomo.

Am I missing something else? Is there any way for example to define a sub-variable of a variable with an index fixed to a value?

related: https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2019/02/piecewise-linear-functions-and.html

The piecewise function in Pyomo is a black box, is rather buggy, and is difficult to debug. Doing this yourself gives you more control.
